# На скольких серверах находиться мой Discord бот? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-3.8

Говорят, чтобы узнать кол-во серверов на которых находиться бот, надо прописать что-то типа такого:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def botservers(ctx):
    await client.say("Количество серверов, на которых я есть: " + str(len(client.servers)) + " servers")
```

Нет. Не получаеться найти *servers*, и я хочу узнать где этот *servers* находиться, что бы в начале моей программы импортировать именно тот, нужный файл с содержимым "*servers*".

Comment: `Не получаеться найти servers`. Как именно не получается? Какой результат работы этого кода? Ошибка? Какая? В общем нужны подробности.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, автор вопроса не конкретизирует, но исходя из кода, у вас ошибка в том, что вы используете
`servers`, а нужно `guilds`. С версией 1.0 изменили. Подробнее [здесь](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html)

```
client.command(pass_context=True)
async def botservers(ctx):
    await client.say("Количество серверов, на которых я есть: " + str(len(client.guilds)) + " servers")
```

Comment: Спасибо, но странно вот что: **Количество серверов, на которых я есть: 0 servers**. Но уже ближе к истинне

Comment: @Ryan ну, тут простой вопрос, у вас бот точно находится на каком-нибудь сервере?)

Comment: Разумеется, даже на 4 если не меньше)